# Cron job fails when executing python script with subprocess

Tags: python, shell, cron, subprocess

My cron runs ok when it's set up like this:

```
* * * * * usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/username/path/to/my/script1.py
* * * * * bash -c -l "/Users/username//path/to/my/script2.sh"
```

When I run the above scripts manually in terminal like this, it also works:

```
usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/username/path/to/my/script1.py
sh /Users/username//path/to/my/script2.sh
```

However, when I try to run both scripts as a subprocess in a parent.py script scheduled as cron job then it won't work and throw this error:

```
/bin/sh: usr/local/bin/python3: No such file or directory
```

My parent.py code:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run('usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/username/path/to/my/script1.py && sh /Users/username//path/to/my/script2.sh', shell=True)
```

however, when I run parent.py manually in terminal like this, it works fine:

```
usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/username/path/to/my/parent.py
```

I've tried adding `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` to my parent.py but this didn't help.

Could someone help with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can python actually be located in usr/local/python3? If you check the command line then you need a preceding forward slash to access /usr/local.

Comment: adding slash actually solved the issue! thanks!

Comment: Great, I've added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a slash before usr/local/python3!

It should be /usr/local/python3

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607413/when-to-use-a-preceding-slash-in-path-names-e-g-for-the-cd-command) for more details.